# Update Template After Observable Receives Value Angular

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

Why is this template value not updated automatically? Why does the div not show?

Here is the template:

```
<div *ngIf="show">
   SHOW HAS A VALUE
</div>
```

Here is the component:

```
//Global Variable
show;

constructor(private af: AngularFireAuth, private afs: AngularFirestore) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.af.auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
       if (user) {
         this.show = true;
       }
    });
}
```

Comment: I cannot subscribe to onAuthStateChanged(), it throws an error.

Comment: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type '(nextOrObserver: Observer<any, Error> | ((a: User) => any), error?: (a: Error) => any, completed?: Unsubscribe) => Unsubscribe'.